# trying to convert string of floats from base x to base 10

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string from any base (2-36) to a base 10.  String will include a fraction. In the code below, I'm trying to use int() ton convert.  Do I need to cycle through each char in string and convert one-by-one, based on place value?

Code and results so far:

```
def is_valid_strfrac(s, base=2):

    return all([is_valid_strdigit(c, base) for c in s if c != '.']) \

        and (len([c for c in s if c == '.']) <= 1)



def eval_strfrac(s, base=2):

    assert is_valid_strfrac(s, base), "'{}' contains invalid digits for a base-{} number.".format(s, base)

    int(s, base)



print("start")    

print(eval_strfrac('100.101', 2))

print("end")
```

​

start

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-83ab061d710b> in <module>()
      9 
     10 print("start")
---> 11 print(eval_strfrac('100.101', 2))
     12 print("end")

<ipython-input-11-83ab061d710b> in eval_strfrac(s, base)
      6    # numerals = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      7    # return sum(numerals.index(x)*base**i for i, x in enumerate(s[::-1]))
----> 8     int(s, base)
      9 
     10 print("start")

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '100.101'
```

## AMENDED to show is_valid_strdigit:

```
def is_valid_strdigit(c, base=2):
    if type (c) is not str: return False # Reject non-string digits
    if (type (base) is not int) or (base < 2) or (base > 36): return False # Reject non-integer bases outside 2-36
    if base < 2 or base > 36: return False # Reject bases outside 2-36
    if len (c) != 1: return False # Reject anything that is not a single character
    if '0' <= c <= str (min (base-1, 9)): return True # Numerical digits for bases up to 10
    if base > 10 and 0 <= ord (c) - ord ('a') < base-10: return True # Letter digits for bases > 10
    return False # Reject everything else
```

100.101 base 2 should become 4.625 base 10.

Comment: Can you show the code for is_valid_strdigit? Can you also include expected ouput?

Comment: What is your desired output for `eval_strfrac` ? What should be output for `100.101`.

Comment: i think you indeed have to iterate over your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to retrieve your integer part and fractional parts from your string:

```py
s = "100.101" #Assuming s was valiated as a valid string
x = 2 #Source base

#Find integer part and decimal part
parts = s.split('.')
if len(parts) == 2:
    integerPart, decimalPart = parts[0], parts[1]
elif len(parts) == 1:
    if '.' in s:
        integerPart, decimalPart = "", parts[0]
    else:
        integerPart, decimalPart = parts[0], ""
else:
    raise Exception("Invalid number.")
```

You could also use a regular expression to split the string into integer part and fractional part:

```py
import re

s = "100.101" #Assuming s was valiated as a valid string
x = 2 #Source base

m = re.search('(?P<integer>\d*)\.?(?P<decimal>\d*)', s)
integerPart, decimalPart = m.group("integer"), m.group("decimal")
```

And then iterate over characters in the integer and fractional string to add up digits:

```py
#Iterate over integer and decimal parts to sum digits
result = sum([(x ** i) * int(c) for i, c in enumerate(integerPart[::-1])]) + sum([(x ** -(i + 1 )) * int(c) for i, c in enumerate(decimalPart)])
print(result) #prints 4.625
```

Comment: Well, since you already separated the two parts, you can just use `int` with base to convert, instead of doing a manual sum, at least for the integer part.

Comment: i actually reverted because the int function is not happy with an empty string

Comment: For the empty string, you could've just changed the separation part to use "0" instead of "". ;P

Answer (score 0):

'100.101' == '100101/1000' (still in base2)

You can get the same result by "expanding" your number like that, converting both parts (100101 -> 37, 1000 -> 8) and just doing the division. ;)

Let's do this:

```
base = 2
s = "100.101"
separated = s.split(".")
merged = "".join(separated)
dot_position = len(separated[1]) if len(separated) > 1 else 0
divisor = base ** dot_position
converted = int(merged, base=base) / divisor
```

Comment: Should work in any base because of how bases work. + If number starts with dot (no integer part), e.g. `".101"`, separated is `["", "101"], so it merges `merge` correctly and `dot_position` is calculated correctly as well. If the number is only integer, `split` does nothing, `merged` is the same as `s`, and ternary operator makes `dot_position = 0`, so we divide by 1.